# Hacking a closed source program to help me sort real life objects with python/screenshot/OCR

Tags: python, image, opencv, python-imaging-library, ocr

In my job,we are using a dedicated MS ACCESS program (let's call it XYZ)to help us in our work.

I cannot access source code/API of this program, but I want to write a python script to help me automate a sorting task (which is not implemented), that I'm telling you.

We take 12 random objects/tools/pieces which are identified by a barcode with a unique id (for example 50286,50285,50277,50280 ....), we shoot them with a barcode gun scanner and in the program XYZ we get this result.

[before sorting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRZpB.png)

This is a screenshot of the pc at work, I added by hand the blue colored numbers to the right just for clarity, to explain to you what I'm trying to accomplish.
Remember we took these objects randomly, now we have to sort them.
They are sorted by program XYZ keeping in mind some important sorting stuff that it isn't important to know.

This script makes two screenshot, the first before sorting the list and the second after sorting the list.

After this sorting, my list looks like this.

[after sorting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eroo7.png)

I want  my script to output the numbers 3,12,11,9,8,7,10,6,4,5,1,2.

I thought this was a simple task because I already managed to get for example Element_#1_in_before_list

[50826 before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/blmnN.png)

and Element_#11_in_after_list,

[50286 after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4xtd.png)

However I cannot tell the first item is now the eleventh element because the two pictures aren't similar due to random annoying noise blue/cyan pixels (Truetype?)

I tried OCR to recognize the characters, but sometimes it fails and it's too complicated.

I tried to convert to Black and White but noise pixels become sometimes black or white and the two images don't match perfectly (I came up with the solution  to perform md5sum to tell if they are the same)

How can I solve the problem?

Maybe it's simple but i'm noob.

Help me  surprise the XYZ developer!!

Comment: It's not python, but could you hook TextOut, and extract the text like that?  Alternatively, hook into the accessability API (used by screen readers), and get the text like that?

Comment: please provide the screenshots rather than links, links go bad...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried matching in a non-exact way? You could match each image in list 1 to the image in list 2 with the lowest MSE.

```
def mse(imageA, imageB):
    # the 'Mean Squared Error' between the two images is the
    # sum of the squared difference between the two images;
    # NOTE: the two images must have the same dimension
    err = np.sum((imageA.astype("float") - imageB.astype("float")) ** 2)
    err /= float(imageA.shape[0] * imageA.shape[1])

    # return the MSE, the lower the error, the more "similar"
    # the two images are
    return err
```

Source for MSE function: http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/09/15/python-compare-two-images/